# what are the text -mime types supported by android frameworks?

Tags: android

I am trying to render a video file in android .
wanted to know the subtitle format support is there or not for the specific mime type of that file.

Comment: android default players won't support subtitle

Comment: What if I want to add in my application.That mime type support should be there right?As far as I checked It is supporting few mimetypes of text data .I want to make sure.

Comment: Thanqq for ur reply

Comment: I am writing my own application and for that the mime type support should be there